# JS/JQ Whack-A-Mole Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 2d-games

Hello guys Im trying to make a JS/JQ game : Whack A Mole.

I have made a 'world' where there are 6 div's that can change color ( to show where the mole is) , I also have three buttons to choose easy , normal or hard.

I'm stuck on two things : 
1 : the button.click does not react to anything ( not even the simpelest css change on a p )
2 : the divs don't change color ( this might be a follow-up for problem 1)

Here is my code :

the p with ID "car" and text "blablacar" is to show the 'simple' click command to change color.

Can anyone see whats wrong ( probably a lot , but just for the button part ) with my code?
Thank you for reading my post

```
enter code here



<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.1.1.js">
    "use strict";

        var currentScore = 0;
        var niveau = 0;
        var currentLives = 3;
        var inAction = false;

        var moleworld = "#moleWorld";
        var field = ".field";

        var beginEasyClick = document.getElementById("beginEasyClick");
        var beginnNormalClick = document.getElementById("beginNormalClick");
        var beginHardClick = document.getElementById("beginHardClick");

        var displayScore = document.getElementById("_displayScore");
        var $field = $(moleworld).find(field);


        var getrandomInt(function(min , max)
                         {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min - 1 )) + min}

        function randomField() {
$($field[getrandomInt(0 , 8)]);





            function showmole()
            {
                $(beginEasyClick).click(function{

                $("#car").css("color" , "blue");
            })};

    </script>
<p id="car">blablacar</p>
<div id="StartMenu"></div>
 <button id="beginEasyClick"> Easy </button>
    <button id="beginNormalClick"> Normal </button>
    <button id="beginHardClick"> Hard </button>
<div id="generalInformation">
<p id="_displayScore"> </p> </div>

<div id="moleWorld">

  <div class="field"> </div> 
     <div class="field"> </div> 
     <div class="field"> </div> 
     <div class="field"> </div> 
     <div class="field"> </div> 
     <div class="field"> </div> 
    <div class="field"> </div> 
    <div class="field"> </div> 
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: please add your code as well.

Comment: You could use a JS playground in order to illustrate what you've tried as well as adding your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides some bracketing errors (even parameterless functions need to have empty () brackets), the `click()` event handler for the button is defined inside the `showmole()` function which is not called anywhere. You have to move this part into the `$().ready()` part of your script so that the handler is added as soon as the document has been loaded.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $(beginEasyClick).click(function () {
    $("#car").css("color", "blue");
  });
});
```

As mentioned in the comments you should also in the future post your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that others can more easily help you. Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/f2ab5t6c/4/) for your code with a working "easy" button.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH